# how to set permission 777 to a zip file?

Tags: php, zip, chmod

I am trying to zip files and I want to set the permission to chmod 777. But i don't know how/where I should write the chmod 777. Could anyone please help me? This is my code for zipping files.

```
$files = array(
            'download.xml',
            'script_.xml',

        );

        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip_name = "testabc.package";
        if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){
            $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
        }

        foreach($files as $file){
            $zip->addFile($file);
        }

        $zip->close();
        echo shell_exec("zip -P pass test.zip script.xml");
```

Comment: Oh lets see... Googling for "PHP chmod" brings us right to [this page](http://us3.php.net/chmod).

Comment: I tried this chmod("/var/www/dlti/myfile.package",777); but nothing happened. still read only.

Comment: check your file path again

Comment: and if you want to check that was successfully `chmod`ed. use this-->   `echo chmod('/to/your/zip/file', 777) ? 'CHMOD is successfully!' : 'Error';`

Comment: I have a similar issue that i believe may be permissions related... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496403/pdf-in-php-ziparchive-throwing-errors - I'm curious if you found any success here?  I tried the chmod method below to no avail.  In my case, i intend to immediately delete the zip file upon download.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code.

```
chmod("/to/your/zip/file", 777);
```

And for more informations read [php manual for chmod](https://www.php.net/chmod)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you do not have the required permission to change file permissions.  I would suggest contacting your hosting provider to have them change it for you.  Generally, 777 is a very bad permission to have set on any file. See: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18280/why-chmod-777-is-not-secure

If you do own the machine, run sudo chmod 777 filename.zip